# How to include related columns in Django without including all columns

Tags: python, django

Django's ORM has a method called [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for joining related tables.

However, if the field included is a foreign key to another model, the default behavior seems to be to include all columns in the related model.

For example, if I have the models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(...)
    field2 = models.CharField(...)

class B(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(...)
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(A)

print str(B.objects.all().select_related('field2').query))
```

outputs:

```
SELECT myapp_b.id, myapp_b.field1, myapp_b.field2_id, myapp_a.id, myapp_a.field1, myapp_a.field2 FROM ...
```

but I only want to include `A.field1`, not all fields from `A`, so I tried doing:

```
print str(B.objects.all().select_related('b__field1').query))
```

but that outputs the exact same query.

How do I stop Django from including all fields from a foreign-key field listed in `select_related()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `only()`, but then you have to include all the fields you want from your B object:

```
B.objects.all().select_related('field2').only('field1', 'field2__field1')
```

Comment: I had tried something similar, but was getting an error because I was using the full field name in each. The trick is to ensure both sets of field names don't overlap.